# How to provide an OCaml (let*) operator optionally, to work with old and new compilers?

Tags: operators, ocaml, option-type, backwards-compatibility, let

I have a module `MyMonad` that provides a bind function as `(let*)` operator, but also as `>>=` operator for old-style code.

The idea is that old code can use it as:

```ocaml
let foobar () =
  let open MyMonad in
  foo "test" >>= fun s ->
  bar s 1 >>= fun (a, b) ->
  return a + b
```

and that new code compiled on OCaml >= 4.08 can use it as:

```ocaml
let foobar () =
  let open MyMonad in
  let* s = foo "test" in
  let* a, b = bar s 1 in
  return a + b
```

Inside the module `MyMonad.ml`, these operators are implemented in a straight forward way:

```ocaml
let (>>=) a f =
  ...

let (let*) = (>>=)
```

However, on OCaml <= 4.07, the last line is a syntax error. And the same is true for the `val (let*) : ...` line in the `MyMonad.mli` interface file.

This issue occurs especially when this module is meant to be used in BuckleScript (nowadays ReScript) as well, which is based on OCaml 4.06 and where it is not clear when they will upgrade to a later OCaml version.

**How can I mark those last lines to be compiled only on OCaml >= 4.08?**

*Note:* I'm aware that I could create two modules, one adding `(let*)` on top of the other and being excluded on old compilers. But I wonder if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question myself, there is indeed to need to stick with `>>=`, the new syntax can be used via **shims** with old OCaml compilers and even BuckleScript (nowadays ReScript).

The latter can be achieved as follows:

1. Create a new OPAM switch into the current directory for the 4.06 OCaml compiler. This is the version on which is the current BuckleScript version is based, and it is needed to convince the shims to actually do something (for more recent compiler versions those would compile to a no-op):

   ```sh
   opam switch create -wy --no-install . 4.06.0
   ```
2. Install the `ocaml-syntax-shims` OPAM package:

   ```sh
   opam install -wy ocaml-syntax-shims
   ```
3. Add the following preprocessing line to you `bsconfig.json` configuration file:

   ```json
   {
     "pp-flags": "./_opam/bin/ocaml-syntax-shims -dump-ast",
     ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the additions to the language or stdlib are followed by backporting libraries usually called `*-shims`.

For your problem, there is

https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ocaml-syntax-shims

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which showed that I need to clarify my question more. To my knowledge, those ocaml-syntax-shims, or ocaml-ppx in general, does not work with BuckleScript/ReScript, does it?

Comment: @vog I don't know unfortunately what's the case with buckle/rescript. If I'm not mistaken, "future syntax" thing for let operators is only for dune projects. I may be mistaken; take with a grain of salt.

Comment: @vog I think the ReScript team has for all intents and purposes built a completely separate language that happens to use an older version of the OCaml compiler. So I doubt they'd include any OCaml features that they don't explicitly mention themselves, including ppxes and (let*) syntax.

Comment: @kevinji Luckily, this is not true. (But if they would go that route rigurously, they would quickly become useless for us, and as I assume we're not unique, I assume they would loose an important part of their community.) I noticed that their very own build system configuration, bsconfig, does provide means for pp, etc., and I'll write down an answer to my question as soon as everything is up and running.

Comment: @kevinji I just added my findings as a second answer.

Comment: @vog It seems like this is true, per the [discuss.ocaml thread](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/a-short-history-of-rescript-bucklescript/7222); quoting: "our top priority is to make the dev experience better for JS platform users, while the OCaml users are more concerned about using the latest version of compilers from upstream and compatibility". In particular, things like ppxes, inline operators, and `(let*)` are not supported in ReScript. Now, ReasonML (the language) still works with native OCaml code, but the future of that project seems to be uncertain.

Comment: @kevinji Thanks for the pointer. It is an interesting read. I still hope that they won't totally cut off the compatibility to OCaml 4.06 which they have right now. But the future is uncertain in that regard, for sure.